# strtotime fails on a different environnement

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have two different environnement one dev, one prod and I try to execute this code :

```
<?php

var_dump(date_default_timezone_get());
var_dump(strtotime("1901-04-05"));

?>
```

Output dev (PHP 7.1.16):

```
string(3) "UTC" int(-2169331200)
```

Output prod (PHP 7.1.13 and tried on PHP 7.2):

```
string(3) "UTC" bool(false)
```

I would love to know if anyone has an idea why it's not working.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem https://3v4l.org/9LPSR

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem, it's certainly related to the configuration of the production server (Shared Host at OVH). And the question is more if anyone know what could be this misconfiguration.

Comment: 2nd machine you have only 32bit arhitecture?